# How to assign new observations to cluster using distance matrix and kmedoids?

Tags: python, nlp, cluster-analysis, distance, k-means

I have a dataframe that holds the Word Mover's Distance between each document in my dataframe. I am running kmediods on this to generate clusters.

```
       1      2     3      4      5   
  1  0.00   0.05  0.07   0.04   0.05
  2  0.05   0.00  0.06   0.04   0.05
  3. 0.07   0.06  0.00   0.06   0.06
  4  0.04   0.04. 0.06   0.00   0.04
  5  0.05   0.05  0.06   0.04   0.00

  kmed = KMedoids(n_clusters= 3, random_state=123, method  ='pam').fit(distance)
```

After running on this initial matrix and generating clusters, I want to add new points to be clustered. After adding a new document to the distance matrix I end up with:

```
       1      2     3      4      5      6
  1  0.00   0.05  0.07   0.04   0.05   0.12
  2  0.05   0.00  0.06   0.04   0.05   0.21 
  3. 0.07   0.06  0.00   0.06   0.06   0.01
  4  0.04   0.04. 0.06   0.00   0.04   0.05
  5  0.05   0.05  0.06   0.04   0.00   0.12
  6. 0.12   0.21  0.01   0.05   0.12   0.00
```

I have tried using kmed.predict on the new row.

```
kmed.predict(new_distance.loc[-1: ])
```

However, this gives me an error of incompatible dimensions `X.shape[1] == 6` while `Y.shape[1] == 5`.

How can I use this distance of the new document to determine which cluster it should be a part of? Is this even possible, or do I have to recompute clusters every time? Thanks!

Comment: how do you compute the distance between the documents ?

Comment: these are just random numbers for the example. In practice, it is the word mover's distance between each document. If the value is 0, there is no distance because the documents are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [source code](https://scikit-learn-extra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/sklearn_extra/cluster/_k_medoids.html#KMedoids) for k-medoids says the following:

```
def transform(self, X):
    """Transforms X to cluster-distance space.

    Parameters
    ----------
    X : {array-like, sparse matrix}, shape (n_query, n_features), \
            or (n_query, n_indexed) if metric == 'precomputed'
        Data to transform.
   """
```

I assume that you use the `precomputed` metric (because you compute the distances outside the classifier), so in your case `n_query` is the number of new documents, and `n_indexed` is the number of the documents for which the `fit` method was called.

In your particular case when you fit the model on 5 documents and then want to classify the 6'th one, the `X` for classification should have shape `(1,5)`, that can be computed as

```
kmed.predict(new_distance.loc[-1: , :-1])
```

Comment: I tested using metric = 'precomputed' versus method = 'pam' and 'pam' always gave better results. I had to alter the indexing code provided to actually get the new rows from the distance matrix. Then, I was able to get predictions. Is there a way to validate these results? Mine showed all the same clusters

Answer (score 0):

this is my trial, we must recompute the distance between the new point and the old ones each time.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn_extra.cluster import KMedoids
from  sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
import numpy as np

# dummy data for trial
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [0,1],1 : [1,2]})
# calculatie distance
distance = pairwise_distances(df.values, df.values)
# fit model
kmed = KMedoids(n_clusters=2, random_state=123, method='pam').fit(distance)
new_point = [2,3]
distance = pairwise_distances(np.array(new_point).reshape(1, -1), df.values)
#calculate the distance between the new point and the initial dataset
print(distance)
#get ride of the last element which is the ditance of the new point with itself
print(kmed.predict(distance[0][:2].reshape(1, -1)))
```